# Improve efficiency of computing stacked world maps

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to generate whole world maps of median variables per pixel. Specifically, I am trying to compute the median range size of the species in each pixel (I have already computed the range size of each species and I have exported it to a `FeatureCollection`).

The computations that I am doing work, but I am running into the issue, that the computation is in my opinion very inefficient (>25min per species). Conceptually, it seems a very easy computation, so I don't know what I am doing wrong and as I need to do this for a multitude of species it is a big issue for me.

Here is what I have been doing:

```
def compute_world_map(species, export = True):

    # This is an image with a band "distribution" with value 1 for when the species is present and the value 0 when it is absent
    species_distribution = ee.Image('imageCollection/' + species)

    ee_species = ee.String(species_distribution.get('system:index'))

    computed_data = ee.FeatureCollection('computed_data').filterMetadata('species', 'equals', ee_species).first()

    # Now I am creating an image of the whole world with in each pixel the value of the species area and then masking it to the species distribution
    area = ee.Image.constant(computed_data.getNumber('area')).updateMask(species_distribution.select('distribution')).toFloat().rename('area')

if export:
    Export.image.toAsset(
        image = area,
        description = 'area_' + species,
        assetId = 'world_maps/' + species,
        scale = 1000,
        maxPixels = 1e13
        )
```

Ideally I wouldn't need to export an image for every species and do something like below, but after 5 runs it gives me the error `Error: Execution failed; out of memory. (Error code: 8)`.

```
def compute_world_map(species, export = True):

    # This is an image with a band "distribution" with value 1 for when the species is present and the value 0 when it is absent
    species_distribution = ee.Image('imageCollection/' + species)

    ee_species = ee.String(species_distribution.get('system:index'))

    computed_data = ee.FeatureCollection('computed_data').filterMetadata('species', 'equals', ee_species).first()

    # Now I am creating an image of the whole world with in each pixel the value of the species area and then masking it to the species distribution
    area = ee.Image.constant(computed_data.getNumber('area')).updateMask(species_distribution.select('distribution')).toFloat().rename('area')

    return area

Export.image.toAsset(
    image = ee.ImageCollection().map(compute_world_map).select('area').median(),
    description = 'area_world_map',
    assetId = 'area_world_map',
    scale = 1000,
    maxPixels = 1e13
    )
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, good point. However I do need the high resolution.

Comment: I didn't understand that! Sorry. However I am not getting any error, it is just slow.